# Deprecation of hash_behavior merge in ansible 2.13

Tags: ansible

We have a lot of group_vars/webserver/*.yml files which are structured like below.

Without hash_behaviour = merge these sites do not get merged anymore and configuring multiple vhosts in a clean way is not possible anymore.

What do you suggest to fix that problem?

project1.yml

```
sites:
  project1:
    enable: true
    pool:
      version: php7.4

    server_name: project1.de.dev.local

    vhost_ssl:
      document_root: /home/www/project1/www/
```

project2.yml

```
sites:
  project2:
    enable: true
    pool:
      version: php7.4

    server_name: project2.de.dev.local

    vhost_ssl:
      document_root: /home/www/project2/www/
```

Comment: ... just for reference [Ansible Issue #73089 - Document the `hash_behaviour=merge` deprecation decision and recommended replacement](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/73089).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the hash_behaviour = merge in ansible.cfg and added a set_fact task which merges the sites.

task.yml

```
    - set_fact:
        sites: >-
          {%- set result={} -%}
          {%- for key, value in vars.items() -%}
          {%- if 'site_' in key -%}
          {{ result.__setitem__(key|replace('site_', ''), value) }}
          {%- endif -%}
          {%- endfor -%}
          {{ result }}
```

project1.yml

```
site_project1:
    enable: true
    pool:
      version: php7.4

    server_name: project1.de.dev.local

    vhost_ssl:
      document_root: /home/www/project1/www/
```

project2.yml

```
site_project2:
    enable: true
    pool:
      version: php7.4

    server_name: project2.de.dev.local

    vhost_ssl:
      document_root: /home/www/project2/www/
```